# Table columns - first using most width, others the minamum

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table which could have two, three or four columns.
The contents of these columns is dynamic.

What I am trying to do, is have the first column use as much width as possible. The remaining columns should use only what is needed to display the text without wrapping.

I've created this js fiddle with a couple of tables. You can see age and country get even widths.
http://jsfiddle.net/7wt7d/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Frank</td>
        <td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Marry</td>
        <td>31</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Country</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Frank</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>United States</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Marry</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 400px;
}
th, td {
    text-align: right;
}

th:first-child, td:first-child {
    text-align:left;
}
```

I've tried setting widths on the columns, but since the last two columns could have text ranging from Canada to United States I don't really want to set this to 100px or something, especially when the second to last column would only need say, 50px.

Is there a way to do that?

First Column (as wide as possible) | Second Column (as narrow as possible) | Third column like the second.

Comment: is something like this what you are trying to accomplish? http://jsfiddle.net/7wt7d/1/

Comment: oh nevermind... i see what you want to do.. my code wraps. let me play with it some.

Comment: @JCBiggar - The United States wraps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css property `white-space:nowrap;` to ensure the words dont wrap.

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 400px;
}
th, td {
    text-align: right;
    padding:0 5px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

th:first-child, td:first-child {
    text-align:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Frank</td>
        <td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Marry</td>
        <td>31</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Country</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Frank</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>United States</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Marry</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/7wt7d/2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xpHZ2/
http://jsfiddle.net/xpHZ2/show

I would set with the col tag the width of your table columns. And use the white-space: nowrap to ensure the text from wrapping on all tds except the first td.

```
<table>
    <col class="col name" />
    <col class="col age" />
    <col class="col country" />

.col.age {
    width: 10%;
}
.col.country {
    width: 20%;
}
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td:first-child {
    white-space: normal;
}
```